# How to google Arabic words with Apple Script

Tags: applescript, multilingual

I am trying to have Apple Script do some google-searches for me. It works perfectly, as long as the word is in Latin letters. As soon as the word is in Arabic, the code doesn't do anything anymore. 
Is there anyone who knows how to solve this?

I have tried using the google-URL for an arabic version of Google but that did not help.

```
set search to "زق"
open location ("https://www.google.de/#q=" & search)
```

This code doesn't do anything. If I replace the Arabic letters with any latin letters it works.

It's a puzzle to me, because when I just write "display search" it works as well, so the output of a string with Arabic letters works. If anyone knew of a fix to this, it would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

What works though is this (you have to first allow System Events to make keystrokes in another application in Settings):

```js
open location ("https://www.google.de/#q=")
 delay 6
 tell application "System Events" to tell process "Script Editor" to keystroke "زق" & return
 delay 4
```